# Transaction does not trigger a Solidity revert statement.↵

Tags: solidity

When I make a transaction on Ropsten from Metamask, Metamask throws a `StatusError` after 2 minutes:

```
{
  message: "Transaction: 0xedceb98a6fa59803022bc688bef7546034d… does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.↵",
  stack: "Error: Transaction: 0xedceb98a6fa59803022bc688bef7…gaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/scripts/inpage.js:1:84270",
  name: "StatusError",
  tx: "0xedceb98a6fa59803022bc688bef7546034d06e00150a9eef276ca771202b4505",
  receipt: {…}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post the contract for which you are facing this error? I had the same error and the reason was me using `bytes32` type in a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You did not ask a specific question.
But it indicates that the transaction failed, but did not trigger a revert which is recommended to restore the state.
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xedceb98a6fa59803022bc688bef7546034d06e00150a9eef276ca771202b4505

Comment: how to restore the state? i've tried revert() in my contract code but nothing happened

Comment: Basically ensure to set your assert/require/revert conditions right.
This will be helpful:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

Comment: I've removed the require() which was throwing an exception but still getting same error

Comment: the `require` is supposed to throw tif the conditions are not met, so I believe it is doing its job. It is throwing be cause the conditions you set were not met.